# Symfony 4 : load config or route based on .env

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony 4.3 app. We recently created an API on the /api routes.
However we would like to enable/disable all route after **/api** based on an Environment variable.
All API routes are loaded using a directory which is loaded in routes.yaml

```
api_directory:
    resource: 'routes/API/'
    type:     directory
    prefix: /api
    name_prefix: api_
```

Is there any way to tell symfony not to load these file/routes depending on the .env ?
Or redirect all request to **/api** to a specific 404 error page/controller ?
I've read about [Routes Loader](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html) but if possible I'd like not move the routing outside the usual structure and keep the standard architecture.

Comment: I don’t know your problem, but 4.3 is EOL while 4.4 at least has support until roughly the [end of 2023](https://symfony.com/releases). 5.x has been out for two years, and 6.x is the most recent. Are you sure you want to go into production on an unsupported version? Upgrading to at least 4.4 shouldn’t be a major problem at least.

Comment: I think no matter what you are going to end up with a bit of hacky-ness with this. The advanced loader you referenced seems the most sane to me. Otherwise, you could use `config/packages/<environment-name>/*.yaml` and only put your API routes in the current environment. The third option is to write a guard that blocks access based on that.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I edited the question but the 4.3 App IS already in production and we have scheduled a migration to 5.x soon. Its the API part that is in developpment and will go in production.

Comment: This also falls under the heading of a bit hackish but you might try using a routes.php configuration file instead of route.yaml.  That would give you the opportunity to check your env variable before actually adding the routes.  You might have to read the .env file directly but that would be okay as the code only gets executed when the cache is built.  The docs have examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `symfony/expression-language` component, chances are that you already have it installed if you require `validator` in your app. It allows you to place conditions in [`routes.yaml`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#matching-expressions).

For this case, you should be looking in the `$_SERVER` variables, and the expression has to be `true` for the route to load; for intance, load the route only on the `prod` environment:

```
api_directory:
    condition: request.server.get('APP_ENV') == 'prod'
```

Comment: I ended up using a listener on KERNEL::REQUEST but your solution looks a much more maintanable. I'll give it a try as soon as I can and mark as accepted if it work.

Comment: Do you plan on having many of those? If so, you might want to look into something more flexible, like a [feature flag bundle](https://packagist.org/?query=feature%20flag&tags=symfony).

Comment: No it's just temporary. But we do plan on having version so might go on it later on